# How to wrap all text before first <br> tag within an <h1>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-wrap

I have text content inside an `h1` element and I'd like to wrap everything before the first `br` into a `span`.

Here's what I start with :

```html
<h1 class="my-heading">lorem ipsum<br />dolor sit amet<br />lorem ipsum dolor<br />sit amet</h1>
```

And here's what I'd like to end with :

```html
<h1 class="my-heading"><span class="my-wrapper">lorem ipsum</span><br />dolor sit amet<br />lorem ipsum dolor<br />sit amet</h1>
```

Comment: will there be any other element before the `br` like an span or something

Comment: try `$($('.my-heading').prop('firstChild')).wrap('<span>')` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bteLzebx/1/

Answer (score 0):

One way will be

```
var $heading = $('.my-heading'),
    $contents = $heading.contents(),
    index = $contents.index($heading.children('br').first());
$contents.slice(0, index).wrapAll('<span>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bteLzebx/2/)

---

But if there won't be any other elements before the `br`(ie you need to wrap the first text node only) then

```
$($('.my-heading').prop('firstChild')).wrap('<span>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bteLzebx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the bit of code suggested by Arun P Johny, I came up with this which will also work if you have several h1 in your page :

```
jQuery('.my-heading').each(function (){
    jQuery(jQuery(this).prop('firstChild')).wrap('<span>');
});
```

Does it for me. Thank you for helping me out !